# COM1 port log in bash

Tags: bash

Can anybody give me script which log PID who uses ( and was using  ) COM1 port ( history ) in bash ?

Answer (score 0):

The `fuser` command can do that.

Comment: @Damir: One can use it for a script which logs the current user of the port. I don't know if there is a standard way short of auditing the system activity.